# DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED

Tags: c#, directx, gpu, sharpdx

I create a directx application with sharpdx and c#.
It works fine most of the time, but sometimes i get this random error:

> DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED

I googled some, but couldn't fine a reason other than it has to do with my onboard HD 4400 or the driver.

It happens when i want to create a buffer, then the exception occurs. I can see that while debugging.

any ideas what i may forget and need to care about? Seems so random. I do not physically remove the device ofc. Could it be something with higher load and the clock rate?

Comment: My crystal ball says that your code made the video driver crash.  That used to cause a blue-screen death but today the OS is smart enough to know how to reload the driver.  Look in the Windows event log for a recorded event about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DirectX application is expected to detect and handle 'device removed' in two basic places: It can happen when you go to `Present`:

```
HRESULT hr = m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);

// If the device was reset we must completely reinitialize the renderer.
if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
{
    OnDeviceLost();
}
else
{
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);
}
```

And it can happen when you go to resize an existing swapchain:

```
// If the swap chain already exists, resize it, otherwise create one.
if (m_swapChain)
{
    HRESULT hr = m_swapChain->ResizeBuffers(backBufferCount,
        backBufferWidth, backBufferHeight, backBufferFormat, 0);

    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
    {
        // If the device was removed for any reason, a new device
        // and swap chain will need to be created.
        OnDeviceLost();
    }
    else
    {
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);
    }
}
...
```

If you encounter `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED` in other cases, it is likely indicates **an internal driver error** and you should see if a newer driver is available.

Back in legacy DIrect3D 9, there was an idea of 'device lost' which was similar, but happened with a lot more frequency. With DXGI-based APIs (Direct3D9Ex, Direct3D 10, etc.) you only get device removed in specific cases. Typically it's because the system updated the video driver *while* your application was running. You can actually determine *why* it was removed by calling `GetDeviceRemovedReason` after you detect it.

```
    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        char buff[64] = {};
        sprintf_s(buff, "Device Lost on ResizeBuffers: Reason code 0x%08X\n",
        (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED) ? m_d3dDevice->GetDeviceRemovedReason() : hr);
        OutputDebugStringA(buff);
#endif

        ...
```

> The one other 'excepted' case I'm aware of is if you call [ID3D12Device::SetStablePowerState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn903835.aspx) while not in a "Developer Mode", it will trigger a device removed. They really don't want you to call that function in 'retail' games and apps.

For more see [Handle device removed scenarios in Direct3D 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/handling-device-lost-scenarios)